# How to get current cron.yaml for google appengine application?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I know that I can upload crontab schedule with `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`. But how can I get current uploaded version of `cron.yaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the uploaded cron.yaml in Google Cloud Console, from the hamburger menu on top left select **`App Engine`** then **`Cron Jobs`**. For more details visit the link for [Viewing cron jobs in the GCP Console](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron#cron-console).

Answer (score 0):

From the Official Documentation of GCP

> You can view scheduled cron jobs in Cloud Scheduler's App Engine Cron Jobs tab. You can also view logs to see when cron jobs were added or removed

Official Documentation
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron#cron-console